# How to get NSIS installer check for SHA2 compatibility before install on older windows machines?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, nsis, sha1, sha2

This is kind of a niche case involving legacy systems.  We're using NSIS 3.03 to install our software.  We have a SHA2 signed driver, but are aware some people are installing in older versions of Windows (7, Server 2008), which got the update for SHA2 support later.  The driver (and our software) won't run on these machines, and we would like to avoid the installation all together if we can.  How can we force a check for SHA2 compatibility before installation?

Comment: I can probably help with the NSIS part but not the driver part. The people @ http://osronline.com/showlists.cfm?list=ntdev might know which .dll/.sys file and version number to check.

Comment: We ended up switching form NSIS to WiX for multiple reasons, this being one.  We are now able to detect SHA2 support and link to the update if it is missing.  There are ways in NSIS that require accessing environment variables and windows package information if anyone absolutely needs to stick with NSIS.

Comment: I'm sure NSIS can handle it as well, the only question is which thing do you actually have to check, a registry key or a installed .MSI or whatever.